# I am unable to give away my unicoins

Tags: discussion, feature-request, fun, unicoins, unicorns

I would like to give away my unicoins to people that I think need more unicoins than I.

Will this be possible?

Comment: Yes this is doge, I would like your unicorns plz.

Comment: How do you get unicorns! All I got were these silly unicoins!

Comment: Forgot that they are not the same thing.

Comment: `DELETE FROM POSTS WHERE TAG=UNICOIN`

Answer (score 0):

Any giving of unicoins between SE citizens requires the gift tax to be paid. This tax is SE-enforced and is somewhat unique in that the tax must be paid by the recipient to the giver. It is 100% of the gift amount.

Thus, if I send you ten unicoins, you are required by SE law to send ten unicoins immediately back to me, under penalty of a moderator leaving your milk out.

Comment: And remember, this guy's a moderator on [softwarerecs.se]. So **watch it!**